# Read byte values, ASCII and UTF-16 chars from file

Tags: java, java-6

I'm trying to read ID3v2.3.0 tags from mp3 files, and the values are of mixed type.

For example, the file will start with 3 chars "ID3" followed by two version bytes of values 3 and 0, and the individual frames of the tag are made up of a 4 ASCII char identifier, followed by two flag bytes, then 4 size bytes, and then the content of the (text)frame as a UTF-16 string.
[example ID3 file](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/3098/20111226104546clipboard.png)

I'm not all that versed in java and there are *a lot* of file reading classes, which could I use that would be the most comfortable to work with in this scenario?

To clarify, I want to be able to read (unsigned) byte values, ASCII char arrays and UTF-16 char arrays (ideally from the same stream/channel/reader object, or at least without having to close one, create another and skip to my last positon), and I want to avoid as much single-byte-casting as possible.

At the moment I'm using a DataInputStream because it allows me to read unsigned byte values and arrays of signed bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have unsigned bytes, but you can read them as signed bytes and most of the time it should be absolutely fine - if you need to treat them as integer values (rather than just bit buckets) you can use:

```
int intValue = byteValue & 0xff;
```

to effectively treat them as unsigned values.

As for the text parts: it depends on how easily you know the amount of text data stored. In an ideal world, there'd be some sort of header value saying how many bytes there are of text data. In that case, you'd read that much data into a byte array, and then use:

```
String text = new String(data, encoding);
```

where in this case `encoding` is "US-ASCII" or "UTF-16BE" or "UTF-16LE" (you need to work out which endianness of UTF-16 it is - from your sample it looks like it should be UTF-16LE).

It's not clear from the sample file whether the format *does* include that information - if it's just a NUL-terminated string, it's going to be slight more awkward; neither ASCII nor UTF-16 is particularly tricky to handle in that respect, but it's fundamentally not as nice to have to decode as you go.

Comment: Thanks! I knew how to get the unsigned byte value like that, but DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte() does the same. Since the headers *do* tell me how long the strings are, and which way they are encoded, that works nicely!